# Getting DNS of an LB with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I wrote a template in CF and a Load Blancer is created in that template.
Is there any way to let the stack 'print' the DNS name of the LB?
I know how to do that in Terraform but i require to do that in CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DNSName` is a [returned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-return-values) value from `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`. So in your [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) you can "print" it out:

```
Outputs:
  ALBDNS:
    Value: !GetAtt MyALB.DNSName
```

where `MyALB` is the name of your ALB resource.